# MySQL: How to insert a record for each result in a SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, insert

Say I have a select

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, customer_id, domain FROM config WHERE type = 'foo';
```

which returns some records.

How can I do an insert for reach row in the result set like

```
INSERT INTO config (id, customer_id, domain) VALUES (@id, @customer_id, 'www.example.com');
```

where `@id` and `@customer_id` are the fields of the row in the result set?

edit: I didn't want to just duplicate it, but insert a new value in the field `domain` instead. Nevertheless a facepalm-situation as it's plain easy ;-) Thanks!

Comment: You want to duplicate the records you selected?

Comment: Why are you inserting the records of same table into same table again? This will create duplicates

Comment: Sorry guys, this question was pretty stupid, I was just stuck with a very simple problem *facepalm*

Comment: Everybody needs a buddy to answer their questions every now and again.  For your effort I award:  [http://www.nerdmeritbadges.com/products/rubberduck]

Comment: I have same issue. For example, the way the table is designed, i need to replicate another users entries but there are 356 records i need to replicate to a new user.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

As simple as this :

```
INSERT INTO config (id, customer_id, domain) 
SELECT DISTINCT id, customer_id, domain FROM config;
```

If you want "`www.example.com`" as the domain, you can do :

```
INSERT INTO config (id, customer_id, domain) 
SELECT DISTINCT id, customer_id, 'www.example.com' FROM config;
```

Comment: But this does not insert a new record with `domain` set to 'www.example.com', it simply duplicates all entries.

Comment: You're right -it's as simple as this - a simple solution to a simple problem *facepalm* Thanks ;-)

Comment: I was just going to write down complicated joins to archive this hah. Thanks a lot! Couldnt be easier.

Comment: You have saved the editorial team of mine few weeks of mindless template changing :-)

Comment: @ArtemAnkudovich glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 7):

```
INSERT INTO config (id, customer_id, domain)
SELECT id, customer_id, 'www.example.com' FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT id, customer_id, domain FROM config
  WHERE type = 'foo'
) x;
```

Comment: there's no need to do a subquery like this. Check the other answers

Comment: Krtek: Which answer, exactly, are you suggesting?  I see 4 other answers and each is wrong in some way.

Comment: in which way are the wrong ? At least my second query and the one from Jeff Fritz have the same results as yours.

Comment: Krtek: If the table has records (1,1,"a","foo") and (1,1,"b","foo"), then the first query in the question returns (1,1,"a"), (1,1,"b"), so as asked, the record (1,1,"example.com") should be inserted twice.  Your answer does a distinct with the string literal "example.com", so (1,1,"example.com") is only inserted once.

Answer (score 5):

```
INSERT INTO Config (id, customer_id, domain)
SELECT DISTINCT id, customer_id, 'www.example.com' FROM config
```

The MySQL documentation for this syntax is here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't want to duplicate each field, the field 'domain' should be different. But it's simple nevertheless and I was just stuck with this stupid problem.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**- After reading comment on @Krtek's answer.

I guess you are asking for an update instead of insert -

```
update config set domain = 'www.example.com'
```

This will update all existing records in config table with domain as 'www.example.com' without creating any duplicate entries.

**OLD ANSWER** -

you can use something like -

```
INSERT INTO config (id, customer_id, domain)
select id, customer_id, domain FROM config
```

Note:- This will not work if you have id as primary key

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't want to duplicate each field, the field 'domain' should be different. But it's simple nevertheless and I was just stuck with this stupid problem.

Comment: @acme - If you use insert, it will surely duplicate the results and if you have marked your id as primary key, it wont even let you insert rows too.

Answer (score -8):

Execute this SQL statement:

```
-- Do nothing.
```

You want to select distinct rows from "config", and insert those same rows into the same table. They're already in there. Nothing to do.

Unless you actually just want to update some or all of the values in the "domain" column. That would require an UPDATE statement that really did something.

Comment: My answer is clearly humorous, and the OP admits to a facepalm. I'm not ashamed of that even a little bit.