# Making a Conditional MySQL Insert statement

Tags: mysql, sakai

So I have this table named SAKAI_REALM_RL_FN that has 3 fields

- REALM_KEY
- ROLE_KEY
- FUNCTION_KEY

What this statement needs to do is that if a certain 2 combinations of ROLE_KEY & FUNCTION_KEY don't exist for each REALM_KEY, than do an insert.

I was already taking a look at [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247530/mysql-how-to-insert-a-record-for-each-result-in-a-sql-query)

I also have the query I was using for the singular inserts:

```
INSERT INTO `sakai`.`SAKAI_REALM_RL_FN` (`REALM_KEY`, `ROLE_KEY`, `FUNCTION_KEY`) VALUES (248620, 8, 308);
```

Psuedo-Code:

```
if(ROLE_KEY equals 8 and FUNCTION_KEY=308 don't exist for REALM_KEYS)
    than insert ROLE_KEY=8 & FUNCTION_KEY=308
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO `sakai`.`SAKAI_REALM_RL_FN` (`REALM_KEY`, `ROLE_KEY`, `FUNCTION_KEY`)
SELECT *primaryKey*
FROM `sakai`.`SAKAI_REALM_RL_FN`
WHERE not exists (SELECT *primaryKey*
                  from `sakai`.`SAKAI_REALM_RL_FN`
                  where role_key = 8 and function_key = 308);
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: Don't think this is syntactically valid. It would need to be `INSERT INTO .... SELECT 248620, 8, 308 FROM .... WHERE NOT EXISTS.....`

Comment: An `INSERT` statement has no `WHERE` clause on its own.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking something else, apologies

Comment: I'll have to take a look at it tomorrow when I come into work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The RDBMS is well-equipped to handle this, if you define the correct index.

Sounds like what you need is a compound `UNIQUE` index across *all three* columns. When you perform an `INSERT IGNORE`, the combination will be inserted if it does not already exist.

**Note that this will fail if you already have non-unique rows in your table.**

```
ALTER TABLE SAKAI_REALM_RL_FN ADD UNIQUE KEY `idx_unique_realm_role_function` (REALM_KEY, ROLE_KEY, FUNCTION_KEY)
```

Then the `INSERT` selects all the `REALM_KEY` values and static values for the other 2 columns.  If the values already exist, they're ignored. Otherwise they are inserted along with the `REALM_KEY`.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO SAKAI_REALM_RL_FN (REALM_KEY, ROLE_KEY, FUNCTION_KEY) 
  /* SELECT within INSERT gets all REALM_KEY plus the 2 static values */
  SELECT 
    REALM_KEY, 
    8, 
    308
  FROM SAKAI_REALM_RL_FN
```

### [Here's a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b92c3/1)

When you have completed the `INSERT IGNORE`, you can drop the `UNIQUE KEY` since it may no longer be needed.

```
ALTER TABLE SAKAI_REALM_RL_FN DROP KEY `idx_unique_realm_role_function`
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't quite sure what you wanted, but here's something that you might find useful.

Schema with few entries:

```
CREATE TABLE ALOHA (
  REALM_KEY VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  ROLE_KEY VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  FUNCTION_KEY VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
  );

INSERT INTO ALOHA VALUES ('1', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO ALOHA VALUES ('1', '1', '2');
INSERT INTO ALOHA VALUES ('1', '2', '1');
INSERT INTO ALOHA VALUES ('1', '2', '2');
INSERT INTO ALOHA VALUES ('1', '2', '3');
INSERT INTO ALOHA VALUES ('1', '2', '4');
```

Try to insert 3 entries (only one gets inserted):

```
INSERT INTO ALOHA (REALM_KEY, ROLE_KEY, FUNCTION_KEY)
 SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT '1' AS REALM_KEY, '2' AS ROLE_KEY, '1' AS FUNCTION_KEY
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '1', '2', '3'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '1', '2', '5'
 ) s 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 FROM ALOHA a
   WHERE a.ROLE_KEY = s.ROLE_KEY
   AND a.REALM_KEY = s.REALM_KEY
   AND a.FUNCTION_KEY = s.FUNCTION_KEY);
```